# VS Code: Error in cross-reference of figure and table (not occurred in TexStudio or terminal commands)

Tags: cross-referencing, vscode

I wrote a draft by latex template from Elsvier on VS Code. But the cross-reference of figures and tables go wrong when I compiled the .tex file on VS Code, it becomes "Figure ??? shows xxxx". But there is no error when I compiled it on texStudio.

The code follows:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\journal{Remote Sensing of Environment}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
...
% this is about authors, title or something like that...
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Results}

\begin{figure*}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.48]{figure_eps/condensed__WG_LAInsc_CLUShist__climatology.eps}
\caption{Here shows the histogram of }
\label{fig_nsc_hist_sig}
\end{figure*}


Figure \ref{fig_nsc_hist_sig} shows xxxxx.

\end{document}
```

In PDF it shows "Figure ??? shows xxxxx"...
And the settings.json of VS Code is

```
{
  "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
        "name": "xelatexb",
        "tools": [
          "xelatex",
          "bibtex",
          "xelatex",
          "xelatex"
        ]
      },
       {
        "name": "xelatex",
        "tools": [
          "xelatex",
          "bibtex",
          "xelatex"
        ]
      },
    {
      "name": "latexmk",
      "tools": [
        "latexmk"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xelatex -> bibtex -> xelatex*2",
      "tools": [
          "xelatex",
          "bibtex",
          "xelatex",
          "xelatex"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex*2",
      "tools": [
        "pdflatex",
        "bibtex",
        "pdflatex",
        "pdflatex"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "xelatex",
        "command": "xelatex",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%"
        ]
    },
    {
      "name": "latexmk",
      "command": "latexmk",
      "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "-pdf",
        "%DOC%"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pdflatex",
      "command": "pdflatex",
      "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "%DOC%.tex"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "bibtex",
      "command": "bibtex",
      "args": [
        "%DOCFILE%"
      ]
    }
  ],
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"latex-workshop.latex.clean.fileTypes": [
    "*.aux",
    "*.bbl",
    "*.blg",
    "*.idx",
    "*.ind",
    "*.lof",
    "*.lot",
    "*.out",
    "*.toc",
    "*.acn",
    "*.acr",
    "*.alg",
    "*.glg",
    "*.glo",
    "*.gls",
    "*.ist",
    "*.fls",
    "*.log",
    "*.fdb_latexmk",
    "*.gz"
],
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "external",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.command": "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.args": [
    "0",
    "%PDF%"
],
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.command": "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.args": [
    "-r",
    "-b",
    "%LINE%",
    "%PDF%",
    "%TEX%",
],
"editor.fontSize": 14,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light"
}
```

The output from VS Code is:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020)
The top-level auxiliary file: draft.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file draft.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file draft.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file draft.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

It seems that there is something about BibTex goes wrong. But I have comment lines about citation or external reference of literature/papers in the draft.tex. I searched this error online, but only got that people tried to run .tex 2 times to avoid this error. However when I run it two times I still got this error...

Here is the setting of texstudio where I ran the same draft.tex and got correct compilation.
[image]

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks a lot!

=============================
It's weird that I just created a small example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
This is for test

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{figure_png_jpg/Fig2_cluster_fig_cut.png}
    \caption{The main land cover types and }
    \label{fig:land_cover}
\end{figure}

The study domain is mapped in Figure \ref{fig:land_cover}
\end{document}
```

But results still get "Figure xxx"...to make sure that I ran it twice, I click the "Build Latex Project" on the right upper corner of VS Code...then view it as a pdf file. Unfortunately, still does not work....

Here is the results:
[image]

and here is the log info for this small testing file (called test.tex). And the original file written with Elsvier is called draft.tex.

```
[20:33:21] File watcher - file changed: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.tex
[20:33:21] Parsing a file and its subfiles: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.tex
[20:33:21] Parse fls file.
[20:33:21] Cannot find fls file: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.fls
[20:33:21] Auto build started detecting the change of a file: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.tex
[20:33:21] BUILD command invoked.
[20:33:21] The document of the active editor: file:///Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.tex
[20:33:21] The languageId of the document: latex
[20:33:21] Building root file: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.tex
[20:33:21] Build root file /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.tex
[20:33:21] Recipe step 1: xelatex, -synctex=1,-interaction=nonstopmode,-file-line-error,/Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test
[20:33:21] cwd: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE
[20:33:21] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 18033.
[20:33:22] LaTeX log parsed with 0 messages.
[20:33:22] A step in recipe finished. PID: 18033.
[20:33:22] Recipe step 2: bibtex, test
[20:33:22] cwd: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE
[20:33:22] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 18037.
[20:33:22] Recipe returns with error: 2/null. PID: 18037. message: .
[20:33:22] The environment variable $PATH: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/xushan/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/xushan/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/laps:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:.:.
[20:33:22] The environment variable $SHELL: /bin/bash
[20:33:22] Cleaning auxiliary files and retrying build after toolchain error.
[20:33:22] File cleaned: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.log
[20:33:22] File cleaned: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.bbl
[20:33:22] File cleaned: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.aux
[20:33:22] File cleaned: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.blg
[20:33:22] File cleaned: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.synctex.gz
[20:33:22] Recipe step 1: xelatex, -synctex=1,-interaction=nonstopmode,-file-line-error,/Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test
[20:33:22] cwd: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE
[20:33:22] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 18038.
[20:33:23] LaTeX log parsed with 3 messages.
[20:33:23] A step in recipe finished. PID: 18038.
[20:33:23] Recipe step 2: bibtex, test
[20:33:23] cwd: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE
[20:33:23] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 18042.
[20:33:23] Recipe returns with error: 2/null. PID: 18042. message: .
[20:33:23] The environment variable $PATH: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/xushan/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/xushan/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/laps:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:.:.
[20:33:23] The environment variable $SHELL: /bin/bash
```

Comment: Hi I have mentioned that I ran >2 times and always got ??

Comment: Yes, there are following text, but the caption is too long so I deleted them and only left few words...But I supposed texts in \caption{} should made the texts below the figure rather than the cross reference?

Comment: Yes, I knew that BibTex is unrelated. But does caption have something to do with \label \ref? I changed the caption to a shorter caption, but still got Figure ???....

Comment: also note the `figure*` has no `h` option so `\begin{figure*}[h!]`  will foirce the figure to the end of the document unless forced out with `\clearpage` as it specifies the figure may not be placed anywhere

Comment: ok, but one thing is that, I am using template from elsvier....so the document class is defined by elsarticle

Comment: thanks and now the example is completed

Comment: If I change the image name to `example-image` so I can run it and run twice I get the expected output [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOdor.png)

Comment: thanks and plz see my answer...I tried a simple case, but still failed....so weird......but I managed the original draft.tex on texstudio......no idea why....maybe because of the configuration of the VS Code? something goes wrong?

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: yes, twice.....

Comment: I don't know....there nothing about BibTex in the test.tex file.....I just pasted the log info here....

Comment: post the log from pdflatex (add it to your question as a code block) if your file is called `draft.tex` you are showing `draft.blg` but we need to see `draft.log`

Comment: ah, sorry for the confusion. The original file is draft.tex. But the small testing file I put below the post is called test.tex...

Comment: ok so add `test.log` to your question

Comment: Just updated it...

Comment: well that isn't the log file from pdftex it looks like the output from the script being run by your editor it shos you ran xelatex once, also the script shows `[20:33:22] File cleaned: /Users/xushan/research/TUD/pub/1/ASCAT_DVP_RSE/test.aux` so it is deleting the aux so running it multiple times will mnot help resolve references you need to kepp the aux file from previous runs.

Comment: oh...I don't know that...so how can I get log file from pdftex on VS Code? sorry I am a beginner...

Comment: isorry I have never run latex from vscode.  you are using xelatex (I now see) not pdflatex but it is the same the file test.log will be in the directory if your file is test.tex. But really it does not have to be this difficult you do not have to use any buttons in any editor. Just cd to the directory with `test.tex` and type `xelatex test` twice and `test.pdf` will be in that directory.

Comment: thanks...this time I opened terminal on my Mac and just cd to the directory to run "xeletex test" and got the correct things...and also "xelatex draft" got the correct texts in draft.pdf....in that case this is about something wrong in the VS Code...no idea why there is a cross-reference error on VS Code...but really thanks! thanks for your time and advice!

Comment: glad you got it working, leave the question open a vscode user may pass by and show you how to configure the build menu in that editor.

Comment: sure...then maybe edit the title and add a "VS Code"....

Comment: I got same problem in macbook air with M2 chip. But this error does not appear in intel chip Mac. It is the matter of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today. This is indeed caused by missing the `.aux` file. Then I found I should set the `autoClean` to `onFailed`. Otherwise, each time VS Code successfully compiles your `.tex` file, it deletes the `.aux` `.bcf` `.loa` etc.

So you should add the following code if you don't have or modify it to:

> "latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onFailed"